# GridView parameters

Tags: android, android-gridview, onitemclicklistener, android-adapter

I've got a Gridview, which gets populated with data from internet. One of the parameters is an id of an element - my goal is to store this id somehow in order to use it in onItemClickListener method.
At first in the activity I pull data with custom components, afterwards I use it adapter's method:

`public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`

Where and how should I keep relation between the grid's elements and actual data ids, so when I click on an grid element, for instance, activity with appropriate id parameter gets launched.

p.s. ID isn't showed in the gridview.

Comment: it is adapter.getAdapter().getItemId(position) inside onItemClickListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a custom object (class) and store all values inside the ArrayList, pass it to the custom adapter to display data inside the getView() method.

And on click method, you can easily have that clicked position object from the ArrayList.